# A localização do modulo http

Tags: node.js

Eu sei que o módulo http pertence ao core do node.js.
Mas, onde ele está localizado? Não consigo encontrá-lo.

Comment: Está ocorrendo um erro na sua aplicação? Pode adicionar mais detalhes na pergunta?

Comment: Encontras certamente na diretoria onde instaste o Node.


E encontras também no Github separado por módulos aqui: https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib